# Fullcalendar- How can you adjust Hour Render

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using fullcalendar.js with agendaWeek as defaultView and slotDuration set to '01:00:00'.

Is there way to change the looks of certain slots ?

For example i want to make green slots that are today and in the future : is 12:00 now and i want that slots that are after this hour and today to be green.

Thanks

Comment: is this to indicate that they're available? Rather than trying to colour the slots themselves (which is hard because there's actually no single HTML element which correlates to a particular slot - what you've actually got is two tables overlaid on each other), I'd use something like the businessHours functionality, or the background events feature, to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yes, i want to show that some slots are available. You can color & block past days but this is not working right for today. Meaning that on today(and if you have the nowIndicator on true is more clear) the past slots are marked/colored as unavailable (and not selectable) while the future slots are also colored as unavailable but selectable. See this screencapture https://prnt.sc/km0dfs

Comment: Well I don't know how you've done it so it's hard to say what you've done wrong. Would need to see some code.